# ASP.NET Custom authentication without a store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My team currently uses WebForms for projects, but I'm trying to convince everyone to switch to MVC. One of the problems that I'm running into is with authentication. I can't figure how to to implement our login process to work with MVC.

Our authentication is done via mostly a web service (we pass username & password and are told if it is valid or not), but occasionally we use ActiveDirectory for logins.

Right now we are using sessionstate to store information about the logged in person. How would I translate this to ASP.NET MVC? I've read a lot about various things -- Claims, Roles, MembershipProvider, IProvider, ASP.NET Identity, OWIN, but ASP.NET has been evolving so rapidly that I'm afraid that I'm reading old information on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Right now we are using sessionstate to store information about the logged in person.

Don't do this.  Ever.  Not in WebForms, or MVC.  It's highly insecure and easily spoofed.  Session should never be used for anything to do with Authentication or Authorization.  Plus, Sessionstate is volatile, and IIS can dump your session at any time, losing synchronization with your authentication.

The solution to your problem is very simple.  You already have the authentication in your web service (though I question whether this would be secure either, given your Sessionstate authentication methods, but that's a different argument).  All you need is the Authentication portion, which is easily provided by FormsAuthentication to set the cookie to allow logins.

You Validate against your service, if you succeed, you call `FormsAuthentication.SetCookie()`, and then you add [Authorize] to all the MVC action methods you want to protect.  It's really that simple.

If you need to have information available about the user, then you would create a custom IIdentity and/or IPrincipal implementation that provides that information, making it secure (secured by encrypted cookie) and easy to access.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! This is what I was going to do if I didn't get an answer.